# Understanding Makefile syntax

Tags: c, makefile

Can someone help me understand the below makefile?
I have comment on the bits I am not sure on.  I have used make files but not extensively and I do not believe I have followed good practises so any advice is welcome.

```
CC=gcc #is CC, libs, deps, obj, etc  predefined keywords or could I use something else
CFLAGS=-I. -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/fuse #same with CFlags 
LIBS = -luuid -lfuse -pthread
DEPS = fs.h unqlite.h
OBJ = unqlite.o fs.o
TARGET1 = test
TARGET2 = test2
TARGET3 = test3
TARGET4 = test4
TARGET5 = main

all: $(TARGET1) $(TARGET2) $(TARGET3) $(TARGET4) $(TARGET5)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS) #not sure on this line
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) #same here 

$(TARGET1): $(TARGET1).o $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) #what are $@ and $^ 

$(TARGET2): $(TARGET2).o $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(TARGET3): $(TARGET3).o $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(TARGET4): $(TARGET4).c
    gcc -o test test.c

$(TARGET5): $(TARGET5).c
    gcc -o uuid uuid.c -luuid

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core $(TARGET1) $(TARGET2) $(TARGET3) $(TARGET4) $(TARGET5)
```

Comment: Read the long long manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Comment: There are tons of information about makefiles. Just google and read the documentation.

Comment: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/ is shorter than the gnu manual.

Comment: What is your confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CC`, `CFLAGS`, `LIBS`, `DEPS`, `OBJ` and `TARGETs` are not predefined keywords. They are variables. You can change the name into any you feel appropriate. Just make sure you also change their reference names: `$(CC)` `$(CFLAGS)` etc.

`%.o: %.c $(DEPS)` - 
It is a pattern rule: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

In brief, it says: any `.o` file depends on `.c` file with the same prefix *and* `$(DEPS)` (which are `fs.h` and `unqlite.h`)

`$@`, `$<`, `$^` are automatic variables for the rules: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables

If works the following way: when making `test.o` object file from source, the rule

```
%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Is interpreted as:

```
test.o: test.c fs.h unqlite.h
    gcc -c -o test.o test.c -I. -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/fuse
```

Then, when making `test` binary, the rule

```
$(TARGET1): $(TARGET1).o $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Becomes:

```
test: test.o unqlite.o fs.o
    gcc -o test  test.o unqlite.o fs.o -I. -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I/usr/include/fuse -luuid -lfuse -pthread
```

So, we can see, CFLAGS reference is useless in the rule, as it defines compilation flags, and the rule actually performs linking. So the right one would be:

```
$(TARGET1): $(TARGET1).o $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Where `LDFLAGS` would be defined to some useful value, or can be left empty:

```
LDFLAGS =
```